# jdatabase no numbers appearing in article

Tags: joomla

I am testing outputting a query in a article in Joomla 3.0.2 via Sorcerer.

When i output the array storing the query only values that are no numbers are appearing.

E.g. say i have 2 rows in a table called 'goofy' like this

- id, description
- 1, test
- 2, test2

My code then looks like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM goofy";

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadAssocList();

print_r($results);
```

The output I am getting in the article is like this;

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => [description] => test ) [1] => Array ( [id] => [description] => test2 ) )

Any ideas why the numbers wont output?

Comment: do  you get the same with var_dump($results) ?

Comment: i get this Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => NULL [description] => test ) [1] => Array ( [id] => NULL [description] => test2 ) ) however the structure of table definately sets id as a int(11) and has a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('goofy');  
$db->setQuery($query);    
$results = $db->loadAssocList();   
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the table name correctly. When using database queries, you have to add the prefix onto the table name. You also need to call the database using `$db = JFactory::getDBO();`

So your query should be like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__goofy";   
$db->setQuery($query);    
$results = $db->loadAssocList();   
print_r($results);
```

If you database table isn't Joomla related, then you don't need to use the `#__` prefix.

Comment: I left that bit out for the purpose of the post. If the table was referenced properly print_r would not return any results but i am getting the array outputted, just without numbers.

Comment: What does the generated query look like (look in your debug).
If you are in Joomla 1.6+ you need to do $query->getQuery(true). I would also do $query->select('*'); $query->from(#__goofy);  except I would also do quoting/escaping.

Comment: @Elin I am using Joomla! 3.0.2. I can use the jdatabase commands but these should work just as well.

Comment: You definitely need the getQuery(true)

Comment: @Elin, you are correct, it was because i was not using the full Jdatabase commands.